# iOS Swift - How to disable only tap gesture in UIView inside the UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell with a third party library UIVIew as it's subview. When I want to select the UITableViewCell, the tap gesture from third party UIView blocked the action, but I need the swipe gesture from the thiry party UIView too so I can't do
`view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

What should I do? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is use this delegate method of FSPagerView to use tap gesture

```
func pagerView(_ pagerView: FSPagerView, didSelectItemAt index: Int)
```

If this won't work for you then kindly tell me more details about this